# Left pad a string with tabs using sprintf

Tags: php, special-characters, printf

I know that `sprintf()` allows to format string. How can I insert special character(tab in my case)?

10 tab chars("\t") after that symbol s.

**Like this:**

```
sprintf("%'\t's","str") = "*morespices*str"
```

**This work:**:

```
sprintf("%'a10s","str") = "aaaaaaastr"
sprintf("%' 10s","str") = "       str"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
<?php
  echo sprintf("f%'\t10sf", 'str');
```

Result:

```
f                           strf
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$_10tabs = sprintf("%'\t10s", '');
echo 'str'.$_10tabs.'|';
```

Result with 10 tabs:

```
str                                     |
```

In 1 line:

```
echo sprintf("str%'\t10s|", '');
```

With n tabs:

```
$n = 5;
echo sprintf("str%'\t".$n."s|",'');
```

Produce 5 tabs:

```
str                 |
```